# Get specific Activity from backstack

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, back-stack, application-lifecycle

```
Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C -> Activity D
```

Let's assume we have this flow. From `Activity D` I want to come back to `Activity B`, so my stack should look after I close `Activity D` like this:

```
Activity A -> Activity B
```

I have used `startActivity(this, Activity B).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` but it does not restore the activity from back stack, it created it again;

When I initially start `Activity B` from `Activity A` I had sent some data in bundle which is lost now; So, do I have to sent that data through `Activity C` -> `Activity D` so I can have it and send it back to `Activity B` when I open it form `Activity D`, or I can some how restore `Activity B`?

Comment: you can start activity D with startActivityForResult. for those cases you want to close activity C also when D is closed, pass some value to the onActivityResult of activity C and handle it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Using [android:taskAffinity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff) could be an option for you.

You can configure `ActivityC` and `ActivityD` with the same affinity. When `ActivityD` is closed using [`Activity#finishAffinity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity()) `ActivityD` and `ActivityC` are finished -- `ActivityB` is resumed with its previous intent.